# spring boot pom ignoring updated property version

Tags: spring-boot

We are currently using spring boot 2.7.4 and we want to use a built in dependency of 2.7.5. I added it to the properties in the pom, but its being ignored. I have done this successfully with other dependencies.
jackson-databind 2.13.4 is a builtin dependency of spring boot 2.7.4
jackson-databind 2.13.4.2 is a dependency of spring boot 2.7.5

```
<jackson-databind.version>2.13.4.2</jackson-databind.version>
```

That does not seem to work.
Will spring just ignore an incompatible version automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot does not have `jackson-databind.version` variable. Full list can be seen [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.5/reference/html/dependency-versions.html)

But you can manually specify the required dependency version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.4.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes it does..... Do a search on the webpage for jackson-databind

Comment: It uses `jackson-bom.version` to control the jackson version from the parent pom.

Comment: @mike628 `jackson-databind` not `jackson-databind.version`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jackson-bom.version` to override via the property.

From the `spring-boot-dependencies` POM, which is inherited by the `spring-boot-starter-parent` the following is defeined in 2.7.5,

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

and and the property is set to `<jackson-bom.version>2.13.4.20221013</jackson-bom.version>`

Comment: Darren, Why are we able to add versions for specific jars , but in this case we need to update the BOM ?

Comment: As as there are multiple jars for jackson that depend on each other to be on the same versions using the BOM makes this easier to maintain, but thats just a guess as its a design choice by the Spring Boot team to use the BOM.